# Without using property how can we access a variable in another class in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

- If I want to access a variable that is declared in Class A  and I
  want to use that variable in Class B .
- I don't want to use Property.
- How Can I do ?

Comment: Use custom methods for returning the value of that variable (Custom getter) or you can notification chain

Answer (score 2):

It is bad practice to declare a public variable without making it a property.

You may also use KVC to access(both read and write) ivar, even if it is readonly.

```
[instanceOfMyClass valueForKey:@"myIvar"];
```

I hope someone finds my first stackOverflow answer helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can declare variable as public and access it with selector operator, but this is not recommended:

```
@interface A:NSObject{
@public
int x;
}
@end

...
//Somewhere inside class B
A *a = [[A alloc] init];
a->x;
```

However it's hard to imagine why it can be better that to use a property.

Comment: Why to down vote? Nobody says it is a good way to go, but since someone asks, is it a secret?

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface Class1
{
@public
    int var; // if you not declare it public by default it'll be protected
}
// methods...
@end

// Inside a Class2 method:
Class1 *obj = ...;
obj->var = 3;
```

But property approach is far better.

Answer (score 0):

The 4 possibles cases that I can think to access a variable are:

1 Declare the variable in class A as public

```
@public
BOOL _test;
```

Totally not recommended. If you need a public variable you use a property.

2 Use a property.

```
@property (readonly, getter = myMehtodName) id myVariable;
```

3 Use a custom method. In practice it acts the same as a property with readonly attribute. Also you can access it with the dot notation.

4 Use KVC to access the variable.
This can be useful when you don't know the name of the property / variable in compilation time.
A little example:

```
NSString *myKey = [self obtainKey];
id myVariable = [self valueForKey:myKey];
if ([myVariable isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    //Do something
}else {
    //Do another thing
}
```

Note that key can be either a method name or a variable.